# When the page crashes while you're posting/editing an answer

Tags: feature-request

I've noticed a rather odd phenomena with the site on a number of occasions:

When I'm posting an answer for the first time, the draft is continually saved and so, if the page happens to crash while I'm posting the answer (which happens rather often for me, for whatever reason), then I can just go "back", and pick up where I left off. However, when I'm editing an existing answer, and the same thing happens, my progress has not been saved and I have to start all over again. This can be pretty frustrating if the edit involved a lot of formatting. What I've been doing up to this point has been to paste my edits into a .txt file and paste them all in at once when I'm finished. This works fine but seems to be a somewhat cumbersome workaround for a wonky problem.

Has anyone else noticed this before? Does anyone know why the site doesn't maintain the copy the same way it does when you're originally posting the question? Is there any way to save your progress along the way without posting the edits? I've found that if you edit 10 or more times then the post changes to a community wiki, so saving the edit periodically may not be such a hot idea if you want reputation points for the answer (plus it would be rather confusing for someone coming upon the post while you're halfway through editing it).

p.s. sorry if this was discussed elsewhere - I checked before posting.

Comment: I think you're right about not wanting to keep posting the edits partway through. I don't have a problem with the site crashing while I post or edit, however. I'm not sure why it would be better for me--I'm mostly working from an old machine.